# Why does a UNION ALL not produce a UNION RESULT?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> explain select * from t1 union all select * from t2;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  2 | UNION       | t2    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+

mysql> explain select * from t1 union select * from t2;
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | t1         | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | UNION        | t2         | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

As shown in the above SQL statement, I am confused as to Why does a union all not produce a union result?

t1:

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t1_787 |

t2:

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t2_944 |

Comment: union all show all the data so there is no need to filter, Union filter out unique

Comment: Union applies a distinct , union all does not

Comment: @jun-li do not post that in a comment, read this first, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

@jun li,

UNION: only keeps unique records
[image]
UNION ALL: keeps all records, including duplicates
[image]